# Inner Product and Operators: Exercise with vectors with three indices

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, inner-products

I have the following question:
[image]

I started off as follows: Let $v\in \ell(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{C})$, and $w,x$ defined as above. Then:
\begin{align}
\langle w, x\rangle_J &= \sum_{(i,j,k)\in J}w_{[i, j, k]} \bar{x}_{[i,j,k]}\\
&=\sum_{(i,j,k)\in J} |v_{[j]}||v_{[k]}| && \text{definition of $w,x$}\\
\end{align}
However I have literally no idea about how to go forward..

**Ideas**

My main ideas are that supposedly the matrix $A$ will have at most $N\times N$ non-zero entries. Also, the definition of $J$ is such that the first index of each triplet $(i,j,k)$ basically represents one of $N$ rows containing at most $N$ elements, and the indexes $j$ and $k$ represents one of $N$ columns having at most $N$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the following estimate:$$\begin{eqnarray}
\langle w, x\rangle_J &=& \sum_{(i,j,k)\in J}w_{[i, j, k]} \bar{x}_{[i,j,k]}\\
&=&\sum_{(i,j,k)\in J} |v_{[j]}||v_{[k]}| \\
&=&\sum_{i} \sum_{(j,k):(i,j,k)\in J}|v_{[j]}||v_{[k]}|\\
&= &\sum_{i} \left(\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}|v_{[j]}|\right)^2\\
&\leq& \sum_{i} \left(\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}|v_{[j]}|^2 \sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}1\right)\quad\cdots(*)\\
&\leq&N\sum_{i} \sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}|v_{[j]}|^2 \\
&=&N\sum_{(i,j):a_{ij}\neq 0} |v_{[j]}|^2 = N\sum_{j} |v_{[j]}|^2\sum_{i:a_{ij}\neq 0}1\\
&\leq &N^2 \sum_j |v_{[j]}|^2 = N^2||v||^2,
\end{eqnarray}$$ where Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is used at $(*)$. It is a combination of changing the order of the summation and the assumption that
$$
\sum_{i:a_{ij}\neq 0}1\leq N, \quad \forall j,
$$ and
$$
\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}1\leq N\quad\forall i.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am not sure about the third step where you obtain $\sum_i \left(\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0} |v_[j]|\right)^2$. How do you pass from the "cross-product" to that? I totally understand that both the $j$ and the $k$ coordinates represent when the value in column $j$ for row $i$ is not zero $a_{ij}\neq0$, but how do you get that expression?

Comment: Note that $(j,k):(i,j,k)\in J$ is equivalent to $(j,k):a_{ij}\neq 0, a_{ik} \neq 0$. Given that $i$ is fixed, it is just the product of the sets $\{j\;|\;a_{ij}\neq 0\}$ and $\{k\;|\;a_{ik}\neq 0\}$. Thus the sum is separately evaluated as $\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0} |v_{[j]}|$ times $\sum_{k:a_{ik}\neq 0}|v_{[k]}| $.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, sorry if I'm drilling this down so much but I really want to be sure to understand. So what you're saying is that if we define the set $P=\{j\, :\, a_{ij}\neq 0\}$ Then in $\sum_{(j,k):(i,j,k)\in J}|v_{[j]}||v_{[k]}|$ we are summing over the set $P\times P:=\{(j, k)\, : \, j\in P, k\in P\}$, i.e. the Carthesian Product of $P$ with itself? I think I understand this. However I am not sure how we can use this to say that we can evaluate the sums separately

Comment: You don't have to feel sorry. You can see that $\sum_{a\in A, b\in B} f(a)g(b) = \sum_{a\in A}( \sum_{b\in B} f(a)g(b)) = \sum_{a\in A}\left(f(a) \cdot (\sum_{b\in B} g(b))\right) = (\sum_{b\in B} g(b))\cdot\sum_{a\in A}f(a).$ This is what I claimed.

Comment: Are you using this by any chance? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Summation_over_Cartesian_Product_as_Double_Summation

Comment: Yes. If a double sum is taken over a finite set, it can be calculated by iterative summation.

Comment: Then is it right to say that at the next step you've used: $$\left(\sum_{j : a_{ij}\neq 0} |v_{[j]}|\right)^2 \leq\left(\sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}|v_{[j]}|^2 \sum_{j:a_{ij}\neq 0}1^2\right)$$ by this version of the Cauchy Swartz inequality? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Rn_(n-dimensional_Euclidean_space)

Comment: Yes. Write $|v_{[j]}| = |v_{[j]}|\cdot 1$ and apply (finite version of) Cauchy-Schwarz there.

Comment: In the penultimate line I understand that $$N\sum_{(i,j):a_{ij}\neq 0} |v_{[j]}|^2$$ is just a matter of putting the summation back together again. However, I am not sure how then you obtain $$N\sum_{j} |v_{[j]}|^2\sum_{i:a_{ij}\neq 0}1$$. How do you get the summation on all $j\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: It is because iterative summation is also valid for sum taken on an infinite set for non-negative summands (or absolutely summable summands in general.) If you are not familiar with the infinite version of Fubini's theorem, note that iterative summation is valid for $1\leq j\leq m$ for all $m\geq 1$. Then taking $m\to\infty$ will give you the result.